# How to code a PhoneGap/Cordova application

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am starting with PhoneGap but I am totally lost : I followed the getting started tutorial, so I've got ADT bundle (android SDK + eclipse + ADT plugin), i used create.bat in cordova to create a default project and I can run it on my device from eclipse.

The point is that the tutorial stops there, and in the default project there isn't any HTML/JS file, everything is java/xml like a normal android project.
So i made a new project from existing sources and this time I used PhoneGap (still don't understand what the heck is the difference with Cordova and if I need both or not) so I selected the "example" folder in phonegap for my existing source.

Now I've got a project with some jar files, but also an assets/www folder with index.html and main.js so this seems fine to get started : the point is that I can't find any tutorial for android which explains how to build an app from that.

Also, Ecplise opens index.html in a kind of WYSIWYG view (without editing) and there isn't any switch to html code editor.
Do I need to install Eclipse Web Platform or anything ?

And please can someone here who understands all that more clearly help me out ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, on the Cordova / PhoneGap thing: originally, a company called Nitobi developed PhoneGap. They were then acquired by Adobe, who open sourced the framework under the Apache Foundation - this is what's known as Cordova. Adobe are continuing to develop the commercially-branded PhoneGap, providing services such as PhoneGapBuild around that, and are also continuing to contribute to the Cordova project which remains at the core of PhoneGap.

You're right that almost all your development once you've got going happens inside the assets/www folder - that's where all your HTML, JavaScript and images etc will live.

In Eclipse, you can install the web developer tools by going to Help -> Install New Software, and expanding the "Web, XML, and Java EE Development" group, then checking "Eclipse Web Developer Tools" and "Web Page Editor (Optional)". Much more detail in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868/what-is-the-best-html-editor-for-eclipse

In terms of an ongoing tutorial, one of my colleagues is currently working his way through blogging an example of building a very simple CRM system using Cordova; you can find these posts at http://www.vsnomad.com/tag/dtw-crm-sample/. The blog assumes you're using Nomad, which lets you develop Cordova projects within Visual Studio, but if you ignore the VS bits, the HTML and JavaScript should still be applicable to you.

(Obvious disclosure: I work on the team building Nomad for Visual Studio. Hopefully the sample is of genuine use even if you're not using the product though!)